# Django models Many to one not able to access all objects in a foreign key field

Tags: python, django

I might be confused however when I check the django-admin panel I can see (will provide a screenshot) , over 50 models attached to my primary model, however whenever I make a query in the code and try to access the set associated with the field I only ever get one entry. I am trying to make one query and check all models associated with the field.

My models.py code:

```
class TokenData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contract_address = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #print('save() is called.')
        super(TokenData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class WalletData(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    contract_address = models.ForeignKey(to=TokenData,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    last_bitquery_scan = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address
```

I am trying to access the model like so :

```
WalletData.objects.filter(address=address)
```

One thing I noticed is when I create a variable containing the filter, and access the contract_address in the WalletData model, I can endlessly query myself in a circle for lack of a better word, by accessing the set and executing a get against it.

I am just wanting to access all 50 models like shown below

[image]

Comment: do you mean `WalletData.objects.filter(contract_address=address)` ?

Comment: No actually, so it is a tad confusing but the way it is named is intentional. The api I am creating is accessed from the frontend where the wallet address (Address) is known, this is saved and used to query various third party apis. 

So the WalletData object is filtered by the wallet address and is supposed to response with all WalletData.contract_address objects associated with the address itself, however even though via the image you can see 50 + objects, in the code itself I can only see one e.g pitbull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out here was my fix:

Models.py

```
class TokenData(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    contract_address = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True, unique=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        #print('save() is called.')
        super(TokenData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class WalletData(models.Model):
    address = models.CharField(max_length=200,primary_key=True,unique=True)
    #contract_address = models.ForeignKey(to=TokenData,on_delete=models.CASCADE,)
    last_bitquery_scan = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.address

class WalletHolding(models.Model):
    token = models.ForeignKey(to=TokenData,on_delete=CASCADE)
    wallet = models.ForeignKey(to=WalletData,on_delete=CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.token
```

I had to add another model i.e WalletHolding, this way when I query the WalletHolding by the wallet field I get all tokens associated with the wallet using a query like this:

```
WalletHolding.objects.filter(wallet=address).values_list('token',flat=True)
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The 50+ objects you see in the drop down are just all the TokenData objects in the DB listed by the name.

From what i can understand what you want is all the TokenData associated with a particular WalletData address, if so then for a WalletData object `w` you can do

`TokenData.objects.filter(contact_address = w.contact_address).values_list('name',flat=True)`

This gives you all the TokenData name associated to a WalletData address.

Comment: So this didn't work either. 

They way I saved the models was creating a token model for each token, and attaching that to the wallet model that was created with an address. I am basically trying to make a list of contracts that a wallet holds accessible maybe I have done my models wrong for this?